# Pushing values from multiple inputs from ng-repeat into array with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$scope.variations = [
    {'nom':'',
     'preu':0,
     'grams':''
    },
    {'nom':'',
     'preu':0,
     'grams':''
    },
    {'nom':'',
     'preu':0,
     'grams':''
    }
];
```

And I display it in the frontend like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="vari in variations">
  <input type="text" class="inputmodal" ng-model="varinom">
  <input type="text" class="inputmodal" ng-model="varipreu">
  <input type="text" class="inputmodal" ng-model="varigrams">
</div>
```

Once I fill the 3 inputs in all 3 items of the array, I'm trying to push each one of them into another array, like so:

```
<a ng-click="test()">TEST</a>
```

And the JS:

```
 $scope.test = function(){
   $scope.singleorder = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < $scope.variations.length; i++)
     $scope.singleorder.push({
       'nom': $scope.variations[i].varinom,
       'grams': $scope.variations[i].varigrams,
       'preu': $scope.variations[i].varipreu,
     });

  console.log($scope.singleorder);
};
```

On my results in the console, I have 3 arrays in the console, but the values of each object are undefined.

What am I missing?

Comment: It should be `ng-model="vari.nom"` not `ng-model="varinom"`

Comment: Put it as an answer and i vote u up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `ngModel` correctly. use reference variable `vari` like

```
<div ng-repeat="vari in variations">
  <input type="text" class="inputmodal" ng-model="vari.nom">
  <input type="text" class="inputmodal" ng-model="vari.preu">
  <input type="text" class="inputmodal" ng-model="vari.grams">
</div>
```

and use

```
 $scope.singleorder.push({
   'nom': $scope.variations[i].nom,
   'grams': $scope.variations[i].grams,
   'preu': $scope.variations[i].preu,
 });
```